# [OS]What queue can be empty ?Running,Ready or Waiting

Tags: windows, unix, operating-system

I'm studying Operating System and I have a question regarding processes and proces scheduler on a OS?
Which queue can be empty?Ready,Waiting or Running.
From what I know(maybe I'm wrong) on Windows the Running always there is a process(SystemIdleProcessor).On Unix it may be a daemon....i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think if **running** has to be empty then **ready** must be empty too because if **running** has even a single place to accommodate it will seek a process from the **ready queue**, **empty running queue** is an improbable situation because a system will some how run at least one process.**ready queue** may or may not be empty as it is a queue holding the processes up for execution(it may be empty in a situation where processor running one process which is independent and does not require I/O and interrupted by no external events).if **waiting queue** has to be empty then there should be no interrupts or external events,but sometimes system is in idle state so it does not require any process to stop running and send to waiting queue to be waiting for any event because there is no new process arrival for that matter,so waiting can be empty.so ready and waiting can be empty but not running.

Comment: please do not forget to accept if you like my answer.thanks!!